# Found nil while unwrapping optional. Optionals should be downloaded from firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uikit, avplayer

[image]This is the tableViewController streaming video when user taps on a row. Just Succeeded to display "name" and "lessonName" in the tableviewcontroller but it finds nil while unwrapping images and I think it will find nil while unwrapping video file "fileURL"
and even video player. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import Combine

class ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer()
    
    private var viewModel = VideosViewModel()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
   
 
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    
    
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
        
        
        

        self.title = "Video Lessons"
        
        
        
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        cancellable = viewModel.$videos.sink { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.table.reloadData()
            }
        }



    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("videos count = ", viewModel.videos.count)
        return viewModel.videos.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let video = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        //configure cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = video.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = video.lessonName
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        
        
        let imageName = UIImage(named: video.imageName)
        cell.imageView?.image = imageName!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        
        
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 14)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)
        
        return cell
    }
    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        
        playVideo(at: indexPath)
        
    }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "VideoLessonsCellHighlighted")
            cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            cell.detailTextLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor(named: "textHighlighted")
            

            }

    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
            
            }

    }

        func playVideo(at indexPath: IndexPath){
            let selectedVideo = viewModel.videos[indexPath.row]
            let url = URL(string: selectedVideo.fileURL)
            player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
            playerViewController.player = player
            
            
          self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
                self.playerViewController.player?.play()
            })
           
        }
}
```

This is the Struct of the video files.

```
import Foundation

struct Video {
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
    var lessonName: String
    var fileURL: String
}
```

This is the viewModel

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class VideosViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var videos = [Video]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
   func fetchData() {
        db.collection("videos").addSnapshotListener { [self] (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No Documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.videos = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Video in
               let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let imageName = data["imageName"] as? String ?? ""
                let lessonName  = data["lessonName"] as? String ?? ""
                let fileURL  = data["fileURL"] as? String ?? ""
                videos.append(Video(name: name, imageName: imageName, lessonName: lessonName, fileURL: fileURL))
            
        
                
                print(data)


                return Video(name: name, imageName: imageName, lessonName: lessonName, fileURL: fileURL)
                
              
    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what throws when user taps the row now. Also it is interesting why it shows "video count = 0" four times, then it shows "video count = 2 three times"? Am I calling data not in proper place in the code or it is the result of downloading timing of the data?

```
videos count =  0
videos count =  0
videos count =  0
["lessonName": Lesson Name, "name": Name 1, "fileURL": gs://tff-sample.appspot.com/Video Lessons/mixkit-hands-of-a-man-playing-on-a-computer-43527.mp4, "imageName": gs://tff-sample.appspot.com/Video Images/1024x1024.png]
["fileURL": gs://tff-sample.appspot.com/Video Lessons/mixkit-meadow-surrounded-by-trees-on-a-sunny-afternoon-40647.mp4, "lessonName": Lesson Name, "imageName": gs://tff-sample.appspot.com/Video Images/1024x1024.png, "name": Name 2]
videos count =  2
videos count =  2
videos count =  2
TFF_Sample/ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController.swift:72: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2022-09-12 12:24:04.606689+0400 TFF Sample[12286:90358] TFF_Sample/ListOfVideoLessonsTableViewController.swift:72: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: What's with the radical line spacing in your code?

Comment: @AlexMamo Just added the screenshot of the database structure. Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line here:

```
let imageName = UIImage(named: video.imageName)
```

You are trying to create an UIImage using a variable containing the URL from which you should fetch the image:

```
"imageName": gs://tff-sample.appspot.com/Video Images/1024x1024.png
```

So, you need to change your Video struct to:

```
struct Video {
    var name: String
    var imageData: Data
    var lessonName: String
    var file URL: String
}
```

...and in your VideosViewModel, use a URLSession to load the image data from that URL in imageName and store it into the imageData property.

And to configure your tableview cell:

```
let image = UIImage(data: video.imageData)
cell.imageView?.image = image....
```

And if I can give you one piece of advice, ***never ever*** use force unwrapping in production code unless you are 100% sure the variable is not nil.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Friend, sorry but I am like the monkey from the infinite monkey theorem, keep typing and trying. I implemented URLSession, still getting error Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'URL', I am trying to find way out from this today maybe tomorrow, if I fail will come up with a few questions. Thank you very much.